# AngularJS directive on click event not responding

Tags: angularjs

I have the JQuery following code in my client app design which I am trying to convert to AngularJS directive as shown below, but for some reason the on click event is not responding (nothing happens when I click on boxes) so can someone help me please by telling me what exactly I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

Original JQuery code:

```
$("html").on("click", '.boxes .col .ten', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
var numBoxes = $('.boxes .col .ten.active').length;

if($(this).hasClass('active'))
{
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val('0');
    return false;
}   
else 
{
    if(numBoxes <10)
    {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val('1');
        return false;
    }   
}
});
```

Directive:

```
 .directive('BoxesDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    element.bind("click", '.boxes .col .ten', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var numBoxes = $('.boxes .col .ten.active').length;

    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val('0');
        return false;
    }   
    else 
    {
        if(numBoxes <10)
        {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val('1');
            return false;
        }   
    }
});



    }
};
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="labelTarget" boxes-directive>
      <div class="boxes">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="col ten active">
            $5
            <input id="5" name="5" type="checkbox" value="5">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $10
            <input id="10" name="10" type="checkbox" value="10">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $20
            <input id="20" name="20" type="checkbox" value="20">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $50
            <input id="50" name="50" type="checkbox" value="50">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $75
            <input id="75" name="75" type="checkbox" value="75">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="col ten active">
            $100
            <input id="100" name="100" type="checkbox" value="100">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $200
            <input id="200" name="200" type="checkbox" value="200">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $500
            <input id="500" name="500" type="checkbox" value="500">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $750
            <input id="750" name="750" type="checkbox" value="750">
          </div>
          <div class="col ten">
            $1000
            <input id="1000" name="1000" type="checkbox" value="1000">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question since I didn't try if it works anyway, but shouldn't the casing of the directive be `.directive('boxesDirective', function() {`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Please ignore my previous comment, yet it makes a difference having it as boxesDirective instead of BoxesDirective, but what if the directive name consist of w words, example SolidBoxesDirective shall the first word only be in small then each additional word have first character in caps?

Comment: An uppercase letter indicates where a dash goes in the attribute name (if an attribute directive), so `solidBoxesDirective` should give the attribute name `solid-boxes-directive`. I honestly don't know what attribute name it expects if the first letter is uppercase :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery code you use `$("html").on("click"`, but in the directive you suddenly switched to `element.bind("click"`.

`.on()` and `.bind()` are not the same. You need to use `element.on()` in the directive.

And as @Joachim Isaksson pointed out it should be `.directive('boxesDirective'`.

Comment: Changing to boxesDirective didn't make any change. I see no harm in switching from $("html") to a sub element? Please correct me if I am wrong.  Tried using .on same thing didn't work

Comment: @MChan If you use `.bind` then `$(this)`would be the `labelTarget` div.

Comment: Just tried moving the attribute to a parent div and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend not using `JQuery` to do all of the class manipulation.  Look at `ng-class` instead.

However, to answer the question.  You are binding to the `click` event of the element, and Angular needs to know about a state change on the scope.  To let Angular know, use a `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the event.

If you switch to `ng-click` and `ng-class` your code will look a lot cleaner though. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried adding $scope.$apply(); to the end of the event but it is still not working :( If there is a chance you can please show me an example on applying the JQuery code in my question using ng-click ng-class that will be really great? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After examining your code, you had 2 errors:

1. as Joachim Isaksson said, you need to lower-case you directive, for example: **boxesDirective**
2. since you are using JQuery in your directive, you need to wrap your element with **$** sign.

**Example:**

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);
 app.directive('boxesDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("s");
    $(element).bind("click", '.boxes .col .ten', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var numBoxes = $('.boxes .col .ten.active').length;

    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val('0');
        return false;
    }   
    else 
    {
        if(numBoxes <10)
        {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val('1');
            return false;
        }   
    }
});



    }
};
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/dxwbb/1/

Comment: not exactly, it's jqlite, you an call it  a mini version on jquery : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: The OP uses jQuery. If angular detects jQuery then that is used instead of jqLite.

Comment: you can try it yourself, remove the $ sign and you can see that your code will get an error, just open your console window.

Comment: Because in your fiddle jQuery is included **after** angular. The first sentence of the link you posted: `If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function`

Comment: in any case, in fiddle you can see that after I lower-case the directive name, the directive is initialized

Comment: but it doesn't do what it's expected to do, because you use `.bind()`.